# Google App Engine failed to update Endpoints configuration

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api

I am new to GAE and API development. I have been getting this error message from GAE when I try to deploy my code.

> 10:01 AM Checking if Endpoints configuration has been updated.
>
> 10:01 AM Will check again in 60 seconds.
>
> 10:02 AM Checking if Endpoints configuration has been updated.
>
> 10:02 AM Failed to update Endpoints configuration.  There is a /_ah/spi handler configured, but no Google Cloud Endpoints service was found in the app.
>
> 10:02 AM See the deployment troubleshooting documentation for more information: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/test_deploy#troubleshooting_a_deployment_failure
>
> 10:02 AM Ignoring Endpoints failure and proceeding with update.

Based on the error message, the problem seems to be the application is not calling endpoints.api_server(), which is not exactly the case as you can see in the code below; endpoints.api_server() was called in the last line.

```
import endpoints
from protorpc import remote, messages
from google.appengine.api import memcache, mail
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue

from models import Player, Game, Score, NewGameForm, StringMessage, GameForm, PlayerForm, PlayerForms
from utils import get_by_urlsafe, check_winner
from settings import WEB_CLIENT_ID

EMAIL_SCOPE = endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE
API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID = endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID


@endpoints.api(name='tic_tac_toe',
           version='v1',
           allowed_client_ids=[WEB_CLIENT_ID, API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID],
           scopes=[EMAIL_SCOPE])
class TicTacToeApi(remote.Service):
"""Game API"""

@endpoints.method(request_message=PLAYER_REQUEST,
                  response_message=StringMessage,
                  path='player',
                  name='create_player',
                  http_method='POST')
def create_player(self, request):
    """Check if user name is unique"""
    if Player.get_player_by_name(request.name):
        raise endpoints.ConflictException('The name has been taken!')
    if not mail.is_email_valid(request.email):
        raise endpoints.BadRequestException('Please input a valid email address')
    player = Player(name=request.name, email=request.email)
    player.put()
    return StringMessage(message='Player {} created!'.format(request.name))

@endpoints.method(response_message=PlayerForms,
                  path='player/ranking',
                  name='get_player_rankings',
                  http_method='GET')
def get_player_rankings(self, request):
    """Return rankings for all Players"""
    players = Player.query(Player.gamesCompleted > 0).fetch()
    players = sorted(players, key=lambda x :x._points, reverse=True)
    return PlayerForms(items=[player._copyPlayerToForm for player in players])



api = endpoints.api_server([TicTacToeApi])
```

Is there something wrong with the app.yaml file?

```
application: tic-tac-toe-api
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: api.api

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"

- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0

- name: pycrypto
  version: 2.6
```

Please feel free to let me know what you think! Thanks a lot

Comment: Is the first file in the api module? What do your app logs show?